# Apache2 with mod_fastcgi and Symfony2 does not properly identify image files

Tags: symfony, apache2, mod-fastcgi

I've been struggling for a while, looking through Google on ideas and solutions of my problem, but I still can't figure this one out.

I've got a Apache2 server using mod_fastcgi, and am using Symfony2. Everything seems to be working fine, CSS and JS files and PHP files are all properly parsed. The problem, however, is   with image files, such as .png files (even the favicon.ico is not recognized). Direct access to the file gives me *Access denied*, while using a file inside a .twig template gives the following error in apache's error.log:

```
    FastCGI: server "/home/{...}/www/fastcgi/mina/php5.external/favicon.ico" stderr: Access to the script '/home/{...}/www/fastcgi/mina/php5.external/favicon.ico' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)
```

My current configurations are:

fastcgi.conf:

```
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
       FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/
       AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
       Action php5-fcgi /cgi-bin/php5.external
       <Location "/cgi-bin/php5.external">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
       </Location>
    </IfModule>
```

My VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:6308>
    ServerName mina.loc
    DocumentRoot /home/{...}/www/mina/web

    # Fast CGI + FPM
    FastCgiExternalServer /home/{...}/www/fastcgi/mina/php5.external -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    Alias /cgi-bin/ /home/{...}/www/fastcgi/mina/

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/{...}/www/mina/web>
        Options FollowSymlinks  
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php5
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel debug 

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T/%D" extended
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mina_access.log extended

    # Enable output compression for all text/html files
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain
</VirtualHost>
```

where `php5.external` is a symbolic link to my Symfony's `web` folder, containing `app.php`, `app_dev.php`, `.htaccess` files, as well as the links to my bundles, javascripts and css files.

I'm not really sure where the problem is, as most of what I've read on the topic is about Nginx + fastcgi. I guess it's setting the whole web folder to be used with fastcgi, but can't really be sure. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your php-fpm configuration to resolve the issue:

```
 security.limit_extensions = FALSE
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried this before and I get a stderr: `FastCGI: server "/home/{...}/www/fastcgi/mina/php5.external/bundles/minaportfolio/images/fon1.pn‌​g" stderr: PHP message: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'begin' (T_STRING) in /home/{...}/www/mina/src/Mina/Bundle/PortfolioBundle/Resources/public/images/fon‌​1.png on line`

Comment: you webserver is trying to parse the image as php ... make sure only php files are being forwarded. i thought you were talking about the dev environment where php serves the images if use_controller is set to true in symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to fix this myself. It was my misunderstanding of the fastcgi configurations that created the problem, and following [this link](http://linux-101.org/howto/apache-virtual-hosts-fastcgi-and-suexec), I fixed the issue.

Here are the two files, revised:

fastcgi.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/{...}/www/fastcgi/"

    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php .php5 .php4
    Action php5-fcgi /cgi-bin/php5.fcgi

</IfModule>
```

Here, `php5.fcgi` is the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# php5.fcgi
# Shell Script to run PHP5 using mod_fastcgi under Apache 2.x
#
#USER=$(/usr/bin/whoami)
#PHPRC="/var/www/$USER/.cgi-bin/php.ini"
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=5
#PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
#export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
#export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:6308>
    ServerName mina.loc
    DocumentRoot /home/{...}/www/mina/web

    FastCgiExternalServer /home/{...}/www/fastcgi/php5.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/{...}/www/mina/web>
        Options FollowSymlinks  
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel debug 

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T/%D" extended
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mina_access.log extended

    # Enable output compression for all text/html files
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain
</VirtualHost>
```